# Can I solder a U.FL to an XBEE Pro S2C module with rp sma connector?

Tags: connector, antenna, soldering, xbee

1. I want to solder a u.fl connector to the xbee. I removed the rp sma connector to reduce weight. Will soldering a U.FL manually cause impedance mismatch?
   [image]
2. Should I solder a co-ax directly to this antenna? Or remove the central conductor and solder an rp-sma central conductor in the antenna?

[image]

Comment: I'm concerned by how blackened the pads you removed the SMA connector from look. That looks like you've lifted the pads.

Comment: Yeah, the solder didn't melt even at very high temps, so I had to lift the pads.

Comment: If you were using a soldering iron, it was underpowered. If you were using a hot air rework station, the airflow was too low.

Comment: "...so I had to lift the pads". Does this means that there are no pads anymore?

Comment: @Rodo Yeah, but that shouldnt matter as I want to use a U.FL connector and its pads are intact

Comment: Regarding 1) it should be fine assuming that the original layout is done correctly. RF paths should avoid stubs for example.